# I live in the Netherlands and I hold an EU passport, but my passport is expiring soon and I lost my id card

Tags: passports, paperwork, netherlands, eu

I have been living in the Netherlands for almost a year and I hold a EU/Bulgarian passport. My passport is expiring soon and I have lost my ID card. Soon, I'll go to my embassy for it to issue a new ID card and new passport.

While I'm waiting for my new documents, I'll be left without an identification. Can I use the expired passport for identification within the Netherlands, should it be needed, until the new one is issued? I'm a Bulgarian citizen.

Comment: Options to do what? Staying in the Netherlands? Travelling to another country? Which one? etc.etc. What's your citizenship?

Comment: Hmm, someone suggested an edit which tries to answer deviantfan's questions. The user who edited has a completely different username than the asker, but appears to have the same identicon. Should we believe it's the same person or reject it as deviating from the OP's intentions?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm voting to leave it open; Ali Awan didn't quite clean up the grammar, but I don't think he's tweeking his own Q. I think the OP is asking how safe it is to be completely without identifying documentation in the short term, and whether he can get an interim identifier from the Netherlands.

Comment: @Dorothy: I'm not talking about Ali Awan's edit, but the [currently proposed edit by "gledacot"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61909).

Comment: @HenningMakholm spot on; I missed that. Same person, editing his own Q an hour after he posted. Should we clean it up, and tell the alter ego to merge?

Comment: Ask for some proof of the requested document to use in the meantime?

Comment: @AliAwan as did I, agree with you; rejected and merged the info

Comment: This seems to be a question about compliance with the Netherlands ID law for aa foreign resident in the Netherlands. As such it belongs on [Expatriates.SE]. In general, expired documents don't satisfy the requirement: https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/identificatieplicht/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welke-identiteitsbewijzen-kan-ik-mij-identificeren. But I do not know how they handle a situation in which it's not possible to retain the existing ID while a renewal application is pending.

Answer (score 2):

As an EU citizen, you do not have and do not need a visa to stay in the Netherlands. As a person staying in the Netherlands, you are required by law to [carry identification documents](https://www.government.nl/topics/identification-documents/contents/compulsory-identification) with you and to present them to certain officials on demand.

If your passport has not expired *yet*, no problem. It can substitue for the ID card.